# How can I edit files in c:/inetpub/wwwroot/testsite on vista/IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, windows-vista

I've got IIS7 installed and have a simple website at:

c:/inetpub/wwwroot/testsite

I can copy files into there, but I can't edit them:

- I can open them but cannot save them back
- the files themselves are not write-protected
- the folder itself ("testsite") IS write protected, so I took the write-protection off (right-click, properties, uncheck read-only, continue as administrator, etc.) and it pretends to change it but then always sets it back to read-only

What is the modus operandi for editing web files on IIS7 on Vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple choices:

1. Replace the permissions on the entire folder.
2. log on as administrator and do what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that the c:/inetpub/wwwroot directory is UAC protected.